# Swfit Data can not get value

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to get json file content, but jsonData always returns nil. What could be the reason behind that?

[image]

OS:10.12.2 XCode: 8.1 Swift 3.0

Comment: the my code is a picture

Comment: Why not using the URL related API `guard let jsonURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MainVCString", withExtension: "json")` ? That avoids the second `guard`. And use `do - catch` rather than `try?` to get an error message.

Comment: `URL(string: jsonPath)` should be `URL(fileURLWithPath: jsonPath)` – but better use URLs in the first place as @vadian suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the file type of path as json
as

```
guard let jsonpath = bundle.main.path(forResource: "MainVCString", ofType: "json"),
```

Comment: No, it can not solve my question.The jasonURL hava value.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MainVCString", withExtension: "json"){
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL, options: Data.ReadingOptions.uncached){
        print("This works!")
    }else{
        print("Something wrong with the path.")
    }
}
```